# Where can I see screenshots of various themes?

Tags: theming

On Drupal.org, there are literally hundreds (perhaps thousands) of themes. As far as I can tell, the only way to actually see what a theme looks like is to install it. (Some of them have screenshots of the actual theme, but many just have what the creators apparently believe to be a cool logo, which really doesn't help much in determining what the theme itself looks like.) Is there a gallery somewhere that contains screenshots of all the themes?

Comment: Click on the right sidebar link : try out demonstration

Comment: Not sure where you're referring to; none of the themes I've looked at have anything like that in the right sidebar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some can be browsed here http://themegarden.org/drupal6/

Comment: Thank you! That's a really great site - it's not just screenshots, but lets me see how it really looks.

Comment: If you want a great theme, you have to create one of yourself. Also why not try out Drupalgardens http://www.drupalgardens.com/ there you can export your  Site (Content, DB, Theme, ...) for your own webserver.

Comment: I know how to create a theme, and for paid work I do. But a) sometimes it's easier to start with an existing theme and modify, and b) for volunteer work I do, I just don't have time to create something from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an answer for Drupal 7 themes: http://drupal7themegallery.com/

Comment: drupal7themegallery.com is not really working for me. some errors and not really showing how it's look like.
I often start with the Zen Theme or the Fusion theme.

Comment: I did find that certain theme choices produced errors, but the vast majority work. As far as starting with Zen or Fusion, see my comment to the other answer - it's all well and good to start with a style-free theme if you're being paid to generate your own theme. That isn't always the case; sometimes you just need to find one that's already pretty close to what you want, and in that case a site like this is invaluable.